# Azure Multivariate Anomaly Detection API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-anomaly-detection

I am trying to follow the Azure Multivariate Anomaly Detection notebook:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AnomalyDetector/blob/master/ipython-notebook/Multivariate%20API%20Demo%20Notebook.ipynb/?wt.mc_id=aiml-17954-sejuare

```
ENDPOINT = "[PlaceHolder].cognitiveservices.azure.com/anomalydetector/v1.1-preview"
HEADERS = {
     "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "[KEY PlaceHolder]"
 }
```

I substitute [PlaceHolder] with my anomalyDetectionResourceName
resulting in:
anomalydetectionresourcename.cognitiveservices.azure.com/anomalydetector/v1.1-preview/

I then use the anomaly detection resource key for the "[KEY PlaceHolder]"

I then get the get the error below

```
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n'
```

I am kind of stumped.
Should I be using a different endpoint key? maybe from an APImanagment resource?
Do I need include the resource location in http string? if so where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url does not seem to be complete.  Looking at the notebook that you were following, you need to append one of the following to it.

```
List models [GET] /multivariate/models
Train a model [POST] /multivariate/models
Get a model [GET] /multivariate/models/{model_id}
Delete a model [DELETE] /multivariate/models/{model_id}
Detect anomalies [POST] /multivariate/models/{model_id}/detect
Export a model [GET] /multivariate/models/{model_id}/export
Get detection result [GET] /multivariate/results/{result_id}
```

**Example:**

anomalydetectionresourcename.cognitiveservices.azure.com/anomalydetector/v1.1-preview/multivariate/models